# tengo un problema en xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

estaba siguiendo un curso en youtube del canal "codigo 369" y hay una parte donde asigna dos X:Name="" pero yo lo hize igual y me genera errores por favor pido ayuda

este es un error
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error       'X' es un prefijo no declarado. línea 35, posición 38.  Appcomidasaludable  C:\Appcomidasaludable\Appcomidasaludable\Appcomidasaludable\Vistas\Compras.xaml
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido

Error   XLS0416 El atributo 'x:Name' está establecido más de una vez.   Appcomidasaludable  C:\Appcomidasaludable\Appcomidasaludable\Appcomidasaludable\Vistas\Compras.xaml 35

Por favor necesito ayuda soy principiante

Comment: sinceramente no entiendo, te agradezco por contestar

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el archivo Compras.xaml  entero

Comment: Muéstranos en XAML completo así podremos ver el problema con claridad.